# Free HTML TO PDF DLL for c#.net in ASP.net

Tags: .net, wkhtmltopdf

Is there any free dll that can be used for PDF generation because I have HTML string in which full html string is there containing table and also inline css style on Tr and td along with css classes.. I tried ITextSharp but it is not parsing HTML properly.

Please help me.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DocRaptor.com](http://docraptor.com) has free plans. It's a web app that converts html to pdf.

Comment: this is a not free component

Answer (score 1):

There is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) however this is a executable file (there is we support for Php and Drupal), however you can wrap it and used it using .net diagnostics to execute it from command line. All others are not as good or not free.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/3c7034e1-e52d-419c-9525-14cd8037932e

The idea is that you use Internet Explorer to "print" your HTML; make sure it prints to a PDF printer (e.g. CutePDF, or if you can afford it, Adobe PDF). Never tried it myself, but might work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've used [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) compiled with [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) to .NET with great success.